# Upload to github failed

Tags: git, github

I'm running this code to upload my local folder as a git repo:

```
cd "Your project directory"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote add origin "your GitHub URL"
git push -u origin main
```

But I get the following error after git add . :

```
error: 'main/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

Why? What am I missing?

The output of git status is:

```
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   PPO_paper.py
    modified:   PPO_strappo.py
    modified:   strappo.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    __pycache__/
    gym_less_strappo.py
    less.py
    less_gym.py
    less_strappo.py
    logs/
    main/
    models/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Did you mean `git push -u origin main`?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is before

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Added in the question

Comment: Maybe the problem is your main branch is ```master``` locally and on github ```main```?

Comment: @m19v The problem is right after git add .

Comment: There may be directory called main and maybe .git folder inside it? Try deleting it and then re-running the commands?

Comment: I forgot that I've deleted my repo on Github, I'm so stupid sorry guys

Comment: @DamunaTaliffato that should not affect the local repo

Answer (score 0):

This particular message:

> ```
> error: 'main/' does not have a commit checked out
> ```

means that `main/` contains a `.git` (hidden folder or file) and hence everything *in* `main/` is *a second, separate Git repository*.  Since you are not allowed to add a Git repository to a Git repository,<sup>1</sup> Git assumes you mean to add (update) the *gitlink* half of a *submodule*.  Luckily for you—otherwise Git would go ahead and add a *broken* submodule—this other second Git repository has no commits in it yet.

If you *want* a submodule here, use `git submodule add`.<sup>2</sup>  But you probably do not want a submodule here.

If you *don't* want a submodule here, figure out why there is a `main/.git`.  Who put it there?  When?  Why?  What did they have in mind?  Is it okay to remove it?  If you *do *remove it, you'll be able to `git add` the files in the `main/` subdirectory.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is an administrative restriction and exists for multiple reasons, including security.  It's not that it's physically impossible to put a Git repository inside a Git repository (although it's generally *unwise* to do so), it's that it's administratively forbidden.

<sup>2</sup>Use `git submodule add` *after* creating a commit in the submodule, since the superproject needs to add a specific commit within the submodule.